# Why am I getting errors about int not matching unsigned long?

Tags: c++

```
int solve(const std::string &s, const std::string &ops)
{
  std::vector<int> order;
  std::vector<int> tnfs;
  unsigned long answer = 0;
  unsigned long opslen = ops.size();
  unsigned long slen = s.size();
  bool loopAnswer;
  bool countThisLoop;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < opslen; i++)
    order.push_back(i);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < slen; i++)
    tnfs.push_back(s[i] == 't');
  do{ 
    //Reset
    countThisLoop = 1;
    unsigned long connection[10][10] = {{0}};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < slen; i++)
      tnfs[i] = (s[i] == 't');  
    for(size_t i = 0; i < opslen; i++)
    {
      if(ops[order[i]] == '&'){
        tnfs[order[i]] = tnfs[order[i]] && tnfs[order[i] + 1];
      }   
      if(ops[order[i]] == '^'){
        tnfs[order[i]] = tnfs[order[i]] != tnfs[order[i] + 1];
      }  
      if(ops[order[i]] == '|'){
        tnfs[order[i]] = tnfs[order[i]] || tnfs[order[i] + 1];
      } 
      connection[order[i]][order[i]] = 1;
      connection[order[i]][order[i]+1] = 1;
      // look in each row for a match in the two column that were just connected
      for(size_t j = 0; j < slen; j++)
      {
        // if there is a match then OR all of that row's connections
        if((connection[order[i]][order[i]] && connection[j][order[i]]) || 
           (connection[order[i]][order[i]+1] && connection[j][order[i]+1]))
        {
          for(size_t k = 0; k < slen; k++)
          {
            connection[order[i]][k] |= connection[j][k];
          }
        }
      }
      bool thisLoopHasOverlappingConnections = false;
      for(size_t k = 0; k < slen; k++)
      {
        if(connection[order[i]][k] && connection[order[i-1]][k])
        {
          thisLoopHasOverlappingConnections |= true;
        }
      }
      if(!thisLoopHasOverlappingConnections && (order[i-1] > order[i]))
      {
        countThisLoop = 0;
        break;
      }
      for(size_t j = 0; j < slen; j++)
      {
        if(connection[order[i]][j] == 1)
        {
          tnfs[j] = tnfs[order[i]];
        }
      }
      loopAnswer = tnfs[order[i]];
    }
    if(countThisLoop)
      answer += loopAnswer;
  } while (std::next_permutation(order.begin(), order.end()));
  return answer;
}
```

I've tried every combination of variable types but I keep getting a message that reads...

> ```
> warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
> for (int i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; i++) results[1][i][s[i]=='t'] = 1;
> ```

Comment: Have you tried `unsigned long` instead of `int`?

Comment: The warning is not from the code you present, but it says that you are using `int i = 0` as a loop control variable somewhere (instead of `size_t`, which you seem to use everywhere in this function)

Comment: The error doesn't match the code you've posted. `for (int i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; i++) results[1][i][s[i]=='t'] = 1;` Where is this? Also, a triple array?! Calm down :D

Comment: *"I've tried every combination of variable types"* -- if this is true, then your situation is hopeless. Maybe you would like to be more optimistic and specify exactly what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

It's unsafe to compare a signed integer with an unsigned integer unless you absolutely know that the signed integer is not negative, or the unsigned type is narrower than the signed type.

That's because in any arithmetic operation (which includes numeric comparisons) between signed integers and unsigned integers where the unsigned type is at least as wide as the signed type (and therefore has values which cannot be converted to the signed type), C++ will automatically convert the value of the *signed* integer into the unsigned type. That will cause small negative values to take on very large positive values, because the way negative signed integers are converted to unsigned integers is to add the largest possible unsigned value plus one until the negative value becomes positive. (This behaviour is required by the C++ standard, and there are good reasons for it. I won't go into it further.)

The consequence is that if you do this:

```
int i = -1;
if (i > a.size())
  std::cout << i << " is greater than " << a.size() << '\n';
```

your program is likely to tell you that "-1 is greater than 42" (or whatever), which might come as a bit of a surprise.

In order to avoid you being surprised in this way, if the compiler sees that you are doing this type of comparison, it warns you. If you absolutely know that the signed integer cannot under any circumstances, including the ones you can't think of off the top of your head, then you can ignore the warning. Alternatively, you can change the type of the signed integer to an unsigned type so that it cannot be negative.

Of course, this won't stop you from making a mistake like `unsigned i = -1;` (which is completely legal, and your C++ compiler won't warn you because it assumes you know what you are doing in this case.)